# SSH Tunnel connection issues

Tags: ssh, port, ssh-tunnel

I am having difficulty with an SSH Tunnel which keeps dropping. i have tried with a variety of ports and have checked the event viewer to see if there's any information there but as yet have found nothing. The only real reference i found was

Can someone provide me with some guidance as to how to locate the problem through logs or elsewhere. The same connection SETUP works with other sites so i believe it something in the client server.

I do not think its the firewall as the connection is established and then drops after a random period of time ranging between a few hours. Any help would be much appreciated. If any further information is required feel free to ask.

EDIT:
I am considering restarting SSH but firstly i need to know why this is required when other SSH connection are not dropping. Would it be the client server which has some rule to drop the connection if inactive after a certain period.

Comment: the tunnel dropping happen when you are working or after a while from letting it open with doing nothing ?

Comment: @Wissam Al-Roujoulah It generally doesnt matter but most of the time it is inactive. Was going to restart sshd but want to make sure there are no other options. After changing the port to 24100 (to see if its a port specific issue) the following appears in auth.log;

Deimos sshd[24100]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Deimos sshd[24100]: Accepted password for connect from 81.149.48.75 port 10444 ssh2
Deimos sshd[24100]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user connect by (uid=0)
Deimos sshd[24100]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user connect